# sync subscription in app store and play store using react-native-iap

Tags: react-native, react-native-iap

I'm developing an app in react-native and having subscription feature in application so integrating that using `react-native-iap`, I've already developed and deployed app on app store but now needto upload on play store so testing for subscription, but here I'm confused how to sync both platform subscription?

There're 2 ways following below but still need guidance:

1. Validate ios reciept on android side
2. Handle all the subscription data like fetch user subscription, check available subscription, renewal dates, etc. from backend

So can anyone suggest me what is the best way to sync subscription on both platform ?